# CAPL Canoe wait for a specific can message

Tags: testing, can-bus, capl, canoe

I'm currently trying to Test Auto-Generated-Code for a Controller.

The test will be done in CANoe with Capl.

I've already tried a lot of things out and it's working good, but now I want to 
test a "message lost".

I need something like this.

CAN 1 is sending a test message 10 Times. 3 Times there will be a Message lost.

CAN 2 which is receiving the Signals has to react to this with a specific value.

I Need something like WaitForMessage(int aTimeOut, Message yourMessage) which gives for example 0 for succesfully accessing the Message or -1 for timeOut.

```
    on timer sendMessage
  {
    if(anzahlAnBotschaften > 0) // amount of sent Messages
    {
      if(anzahlAnBotschaften % 3 == 0) // 3 times message lost
      {
        botschaftWirdGesendet = 0;  
        lRet = ???? here is the part where i want to wait for a an answer from CAN2 
        if(lRet != 0)
        {
          TestStepPass("010.1", "SNA was triggered");
        }
        else
        {
          TestStepFail("010.1", "Timeout was triggered, but no SNA was found");
         }
      }
      else
      {
        botschaftWirdGesendet = 1;
        output(sendingCan_BrkSys);
        lRet = TestGetWaitEventMsgData(receivingCan_aMessage);
        if(lRet == 0) 
        {
          // same for the positive case
        }
      }
      anzahlAnBotschaften -- ;
      setTimer(botschaftsAusfall,20);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the Problem? Just use CAPL-function *testWaitForMessage* as described in help.

You are using Test-Node as there is *TestStepFail/Pass* call in your code, so everything you need in terms of control your test-sequence begins with *test*...

p.s. something else, I doubt that with this code you can detect what is described in comment

```
if(anzahlAnBotschaften % 3 == 0) // 3 times message lost
```

anzahlAnBotschaften = in *german* this means the count of received messages. So when, as described above, you will receive 7 from 10 messages (*anzahlAnBotschaften* == 7) than this condition is *false*.

Comment: Hello, 
I used the testWaitForMessage and it works, thank you.
I searched for such a function but didn't knew the excact function Name.